# Comparing Decimal numbers on Solaris Smart OS

Tags: bash

I am trying to compare two numbers of float data type using bc -l, however it is not working as expected and I am seeing the following error. This is being run on a Solaris machine.

```
$ echo "10.0>10.1" | bc
```

> syntax error on line 1, teletype

Operating system: Solaris

```
$ uname -a

SunOS cmh-contactssdd-001 5.11 joyent_20170315T185612Z i86pc i386 i86pc Solaris
```

However, if I run it on my local Mac OSX it does work as expected.

```
C02RR4URG8WN:roles sgone$ echo "10.0>10.1" | bc

0
```

Any suggestions on this is appreciated. Please let me know if there are any alternative ways I can use for comparing decimal numbers.

Thanks,
Sajan Gone.

Answer (score 0):

You can try rounding off the to the nearest number and then compare in SunOS.

```
x=10.3
y=11

x=${x%%.*}
if [ "$x" -gt "$y" ]; then
echo "x is greater"
else
echo "y is greater"
fi
```

In Linux, when trying to compare two float numbers or any two numbers:

```
if [ 1 -eq "$(echo "${x} > ${y}" | bc)" ]; then 
echo "x is greater"
else
echo "y is greater"
fi
```

Hope this helps.